# Jade: Translate bootstrap progress bar code into jade format

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, pug

So I would like to implement the following into my jade template:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
    <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
</div>
```

It is one of the progress bar snippets. I wanted to translate this into jade and this is what i've come up with given the [documentation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/):

```
div(class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%")
   span(class="sr-only")45% Complete
```

I also read that for classes you can do, for example:

```
div.progress-bar progress-bar striped active
```

but what about the other attributes? In any case, I need help to translate the above html into the correct jade format. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, Jade was based on [Haml and Slim](http://vschart.com/compare/jade-template-engin/vs/haml/vs/slim-lang). If that's the case, you should be able to string the classes together, like `div.progress-bar.progress-bar.striped.active`. Furthermore, you probably don't need that beginning `div`, making it `.progress-bar.progress-bar.striped.active`.

The other attributes have to be done in the manner you were already doing them.
Therefore, the final code block would be

```
.progress-bar.progress-bar.striped.active(role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%")
   span.sr-only 45% Complete
```